# Knapsack for each weight having multiple values - Is it possible to solve?

Tags: np-complete, knapsack-problem, np-hard

I have a 0/1 minimization Knapsack problem with a sum equality constraint. However, more interestingly, my weights can take values between 0:15. My question is, can I really solve this problem in polynomial time and, if yes, how?

By the way, I have n=100 items, all of whose weights (w_i) can be between 0 and 15. In addition, my values (v_i) change for each item when the weight changes in the given range. Also my equality value is 212.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the changing value? When you say the weight changes, does it mean that the object gets heavier or lighter? A small numerical example would help answer your question.

Comment: Ok maybe an example can be like this:
If w_i increases the error value v_i increases too. However, the relationship is not linear but maybe the assumption that (w_i, v_i ) curve will be convex can be taken as true. Therefore, I have 100 different items (i=1:n) determining w and v, the sum of weights should be 212 where sum of the v_i's will be minimum. As I said only thing we can assume is that for any i, w_i increases ==> u_i increases.